# Rails - select a file from local and store it as uploaded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload, selection

I am interested to select a file from my local with Rails, so to  be able to recall the following methods:

- original_filename;
- read;

without need to use of a  form.

Is it possible?

Luca

Comment: What do you mean by "from my local"? The server where your Rails app is deployed?

Comment: I guess yes. I mean: root/app/folder..

Comment: I mean that original_filename is a ruby method ( http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/UploadedFile/original_filename ), but I am unable to import a file as an instance which accepts this method. Both File.read(..).original_filename and .open(..).original_filename report the error 'no method found'

Answer (score 0):

I found the right method

Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile.new( path )